# Can I make some text visible to a user only if they viewing their own profile but not somebody else's?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am using the BuddyPress plugin with WP-Job-Manager plugin for my website. I am also using another plugin called BP-job-manager to display users resumes on their Buddypress profiles. Unfortunately the BP-Job-manager Plugin is a little buggy and is not supported.

Currently when a user is logged in and they visit their own profile they can click the "resumes" tab and there is some text which states "Your resume can be viewed, edited or removed below." and underneath they have options to view, edit or remove their own resumes when they hover over it.

If a user is logged in and selects to view another users profile they can also view the other users resumes but they do not have the options to edit or remove somebody else's resume but the text "Your resume can be viewed, edited or removed below." is still visible.

This is how it looks when I inspect it:

https://prnt.sc/qskqbd

But I only wanted the text "Your resume can be viewed, edited or removed below." to be visible if the user who is logged in is looking at their own profile, not if the user logged in viewing somebody else's.

I have put the following code in the functions.php file:

```
/**
 * Display the Your resume can be viewed, edited or removed below. text on users BP profile when they are logged in
 */

if (is_user_logged_in() && bp_is_my_profile()) {
    echo '<p>Your resume can be viewed, edited or removed below. </p>'; 
}
```

But for some reason it is now showing the text "Your resume can be viewed, edited or removed below." in the header whenever anybody is logged in.

and it has also changed the layout slightly: https://prnt.sc/ra6682

I was just wondering if there was a way to edit this code to make it apply to the text on the buddypress profile where it was originally?

Comment: Delete that `if` statement from functions.php.  In BP-job-manager, find that text and wrap it with that `if` statement.

Comment: @shanebp , hi thanks for this! I have looked in all the PHP files in the folder for the bp-job-manager plugin but I cannot find this text. I was just wondering whether there was any easy way to locate it, when I inspected it it says html doc at the top so wasn't sure whether it was a PHP file I should be looking for. it looks like this [link](https://prnt.sc/rgbg64)

Comment: Maybe it comes from this: https://wpjobmanager.com/add-ons/resume-manager/

Comment: @shanebp , thank you very much for this! Yes, I finally found it, it was in the resume-manager folder, in the 'candidate-dashboard.php' file. I have added the `if` statement to it but it is just showing the code at the front end now like this [link](https://prnt.sc/rgjkh2) so I think it must be the right folder but I'm not sure why the code isn't working. I have edited a few times but still it doesn't seem to be working for me as it was in the header file. This is what i did [link](https://prnt.sc/rgjmie)

Comment: You need to learn how to step in and out of php in your html using php  open and close tags.

Comment: @shanebp , Ahh ok, I will look into this. Thank you for all your help!!